# Woocommerce mini cart widgets not updating without refreshing browser

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am using Woocommerce cart widget in the header, Add to basket behaviour in Woocoomerce is set to "Enable AJAX add to basket buttons on archives", But product counter is not showing how many products have been added to the cart without refreshing the page.

Can anyone explain what can be the issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I had a similar problem and it was something at server side caching the response. If not check if there are some js errors in the developer console blocking javascript execution.

Comment: There are no cache plugin on server side and i also disabled that on client side and there is also no javascript error i checked in the console.

Comment: With server side technology I was referring to web server side, such as Varnish.

Comment: Ok i will ask to the hosting provider, but i also have add to wishlist icon in header it's working fine.

Comment: I checked with hosting there is no varnish installed on the server side. Still exist the problem.